# Element type is invalid with react-native-modalbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display a modal box from react-native-modalbox.

The following code shows the error "Invariant violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in."

```
// React
import * as React from "react";
import * as RN from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Managers
import { StyleManager } from "../../../managers/StyleManager";

// Components
import Touchable from "../../components/Touchable";
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import Button from 'react-native-button';

import { Screen } from "../Screen";

const style = StyleManager.style.SearchScreen;
const ICON_SIZE = 15;

export default connect((state) => state)(class MyScreen extends Screen {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            isDisabled: false,
            swipeToClose: true,
            sliderValue: 0.3
        };
    }

    onClose() {
        console.log('Modal just closed');
    }

    onOpen() {
        console.log('Modal just openned');
    }

    onClosingState(state) {
        console.log('the open/close of the swipeToClose just changed');
    }

    public renderScreen() {
        return (

            /* Full screen container */
            <RN.View style={style.screenContainer}>

                {/* Top container */}
                <RN.View style={style.topContainer}>
                    <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal1.open()} style={style.btn}>Basic modal</Button>
                </RN.View>

                {/* Bottom container */}
                <RN.View style={style.bottomContainer}>

                <Modal
                    style={[style.modal, style.modal1]}
                    ref={"modal1"}
                    swipeToClose={this.state.swipeToClose}
                    onClosed={this.onClose}
                    onOpened={this.onOpen}
                    onClosingState={this.onClosingState}>
                    <RN.Text style={style.text}>Basic modal</RN.Text>
                    <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ swipeToClose: !this.state.swipeToClose })} style={style.btn}>Disable swipeToClose({this.state.swipeToClose ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
                </Modal>

            </RN.View>

        );
    }
});
```

The error comes from the Modal part but I can't find what's exactly wrong with it. Where is the mistake ?

Here you can see a working code using the same react-native-modalbox component:
https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public renderScreen() {
```

To

```
render() {
```